# Выводит комментарии на всех страницах

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mvc

Сделал простую систему комментариев на Laravel 7.
Но проблема в том что я что то где то забыл указать и получается что комментарии выходят на всех страницах одни.
`ComentsController.php`

```
<?php
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        $cometn = New Coments;
        $cometn->name = $request->input('name');
        $cometn->body = $request->input('body');
        $cometn->save();
        return rederict('project/{project}->with('success', 'Добавлен новый комментарий');
    }
```

`Coments.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coments extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'coments';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

Как я понял в миграции , надо сделать наследование проекта для таблицы.
`create_coments_table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateComentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('coments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('coments');
    }
}
```

То есть добавить код необходимо

```
$table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Если эта строчка верна, то как мне в дальнейшем привязать комментарии именно к тому проекту в котором они создаются ?

Comment: [Laravel Eloquent Relations: One-To-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) - даже пример в офф документации практически вам подходящий. Лень зайти прочитать?

Comment: `return rederict('project/{project}->with('success', 'Добавлен новый комментарий');` - вас в этой строке ничего не смущает? И то что вы кинули практически не нужно/не касается вашей проблемы

Comment: @InDevX, на самом деле да, я просто его быстренько накатал для более понятного вида. Эта строчка не касается вывода